# add an echo php to an jQuery windows confirm()

Tags: php, jquery

I need to view an a simply confirm message before send a submit form.

I've an variable that contain a value to print in a popup windows.

how to insert an echo in a windows **confirm()**?

```
$('#mess').submit(function() {
    var conf = confirm("you are sent the message to<?php echo $count; ?>customer, Do you want to send?");
    return conf;
});
```

Comment: First: Do you write this javascript to the page each time you run the page script?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I guess you and me playing catch me if you can, and I guess there are far better ways to do that, but let's see what he is going to reply

Comment: you can use data attribute also on `#mess` and print it in `confirm()`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is wrong with the given code?

Comment: the code as it is, returns a string like this: you are sent the message to<?php echo $count; ?>customer, Do you want to send? http://jsfiddle.net/0js9rz4c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a much better practice to avoid mixing PHP and JavaScript. The reason being is that PHP gets executed on the **server** whereas JavaScript gets executed via the **browser**. Mixing the two could lead to some unexpected behaviour.

The much preferred method is to assign [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes to a DOM element. This can be retrieved via the [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method jQuery has.

Below is an example of how to use:

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="jsInfo" data-count="<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#mess').submit(function()
{
    return confirm(
        'you are sent the message to'+ 
        $('#jsInfo').attr('data-count') +
        'customer, Do you want to send?'
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I do it but you could use submit handler and do something like:

```
$('#yourFormButton').click(function(e) { e.PreventDefault() }
```

The default action of the submit button is to submit the form so you need to stop that action from happening.

An alternative and the way I use, the button on your form should be of type="button" and not submit, then use the following:

```
$('#yourFormButton').click(function()
{ 
    var conf = confirm("you are sent the message to<?php echo $count; ?>customer, Do you want to send?");

    if(conf){
        $('#mess').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why this makes a difference? What is wrong with a `submit` handler?

Comment: It is just the way I tend to do it but you could use submit handler and do something like: $('#yourFormButton').click(function(e) { e.PreventDefault() } as the default action of the submit button is to submit the form so you need to stop that action from happening.

Comment: Please add such explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: No worries, I added it